# Radio button change css when clicked

Tags: html, css, background, radio-button

Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/JHMqG/

I'm trying to figure out how to change the background of the radio button when clicked.

So far, I've been successful with the cat option, but I'm stuck at the dog option. I need the dog option to work because I want the background change to include the circle button.

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this:

### [*DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/JHMqG/3/)

I changed a bit the HTML:

```
<div>
<input type="radio" name=1 Value=420 id="a1">
<label for="a1" class="radiostyle" >Cat ($420)</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name=1 Value=375 id="a2">
    <label for="a2" class="radiostyle">Dog ($375)</label>
</div>
```

and added a few bits to the CSS, so it now looks like this:

```
div { margin: .5em; }
input, label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
input[type=radio] { margin-right: -1.65em; z-index: 2; }
.radiostyle{
    background-color: #CCC;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 1.75em;
}

.radiostyle:hover{
    background-color: #0F6;    
    cursor:pointer;
}
    
input[type=radio]:checked+label {
    /* Or `#a1:checked+label` if you only want it for that input */
    background-color: #0F6;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/JHMqG/1/
On the dog, the `label` element only contained the text. On the cat, the `label` element contained the text and the radio button. Also, I cleaned up your HTML a bit.

Comment: You'd have to use Javascript for that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `<input>` was just preceding the `<label>` in the cat option, but in the dog option the `<input>` was **inside** the`<label`.

I corrected it by moving the `<input>` of the dog option to be preceding the label, you can see it working here:

[**http://jsfiddle.net/SxPvz/**](http://jsfiddle.net/SxPvz/)

Comment: I know this way works, but i want the green background to encompass the radio button