# CSS - li background color on checked radio

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I am stuck with this code. I want to change the background color of the li when the respective radio button is selected. Please see attached fiddle for a demo.

Is it possible to do without editing the original html as this is produced by a core file that I don't really want to edit?

```css
.wc-deposits-wrapper .wc-deposits-option li {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.wc-deposits-wrapper .wc-deposits-option {
  list-style: none outside;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wc-deposits-wrapper wc-deposits-optional">
  <ul class="wc-deposits-option">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="wc_deposit_option" value="yes" id="wc- 
    option-pay-deposit">
      <label for="wc-option-pay-deposit">
    Option 1    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="wc_deposit_option" value="no" id="wc-option- 
    pay-full" checked="checked">
      <label for="wc-option-pay-full">
    Option 2    </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radio button change css when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437381/radio-button-change-css-when-clicked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need to change the color of the parent `li`. In this case this is how I am doing it.

```js
let imps = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll(".wc-deposits-option [type='radio']")
);

imps.map((r) => {
  r.addEventListener("change", () => action(r));
  window.onload = (() => action(r));
});


function action(r){
// this function is called when the window loads & when a radio button is clicked
  imps.map( R => {R.parentElement.style.background = "white";})
  
    if (r.checked) {
      r.parentElement.style.background = "gold";
  } 
}
```

```css
.wc-deposits-wrapper .wc-deposits-option li {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.wc-deposits-wrapper .wc-deposits-option {
  list-style: none outside;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wc-deposits-wrapper wc-deposits-optional">
  <ul class="wc-deposits-option">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="wc_deposit_option" value="yes" id="wc- 
    option-pay-deposit">
      <label for="wc-option-pay-deposit">
    Option 1    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="wc_deposit_option" value="no" id="wc-option- 
    pay-full" checked="checked">
      <label for="wc-option-pay-full">
    Option 2    </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I hope this is what you need.

UPDATE

Yet an other JavaScript solution is to check the radio when you click the `<li>`parent. I think this is more UI friendly.

```js
let lis = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll(".wc-deposits-option li")
);

lis.map((li) => {
  li.addEventListener("click", () => action(li));
  window.onload = (() => action(li));
});

function action(li){
  lis.map((_li) => {_li.style.background = "white"});
  let thisRadio = li.querySelector("[type='radio']");
    thisRadio.checked = true;
    li.style.background = "gold"
}
```

```css
.wc-deposits-wrapper .wc-deposits-option li {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.wc-deposits-wrapper .wc-deposits-option {
  list-style: none outside;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wc-deposits-wrapper wc-deposits-optional">
  <ul class="wc-deposits-option">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="wc_deposit_option" value="yes" id="wc- 
    option-pay-deposit">
      <label for="wc-option-pay-deposit">
    Option 1    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="wc_deposit_option" value="no" id="wc-option- 
    pay-full" checked="checked">
      <label for="wc-option-pay-full">
    Option 2    </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Enxaneta, This works great if it is changed. Is there anyway to make it work on page load and on change ? so the background is colored on page load when the default option is already checked ? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Col ᴸᴬᴢᴬᴿᵁᴤ Smith I've updated the javaScript. Now the same action function is called when the page loads and when a radio button is selected. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Since @kevin-lewis already mentioned, that there are no parent selectors in css, in order to have a pure css solution, we need to cheat a bit with styling the `<label>` tag, so that it fills the whole parent `<li>` element (using absolute positioning) and has the same margins and borders. The only fiddly bit that may not work reliably is the left padding of the styled `<label>` - it has to take into account the width of the radio button - hence the "magic" 2.6em.

```css
.wc-deposits-wrapper .wc-deposits-option li {
    padding: .5em 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 49%;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.wc-deposits-wrapper .wc-deposits-option {
    list-style: none outside;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 2em;
}

input:checked + label{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    padding-left: 2.6em;
    border: 1px transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wc-deposits-wrapper wc-deposits-optional">
  <ul class="wc-deposits-option">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="wc_deposit_option" value="yes" id="wc-option-pay-deposit">
        <label for="wc-option-pay-deposit">
Option 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="wc_deposit_option" value="no" id="wc-option-pay-full" checked="checked">
        <label for="wc-option-pay-full">
Option 2</label> 
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onclicks for each radio element

```
<div class="wc-deposits-wrapper wc-deposits-optional">
  <ul class="wc-deposits-option">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" onclick = "toggleBackground(true)" name="wc_deposit_option" value="yes" id="wc- 
option-pay-deposit">
        <label for="wc-option-pay-deposit">
Option 1    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" onclick = "toggleBackground(false)" name="wc_deposit_option" value="no" id="wc-option- 
pay-full" checked="checked">
        <label for="wc-option-pay-full">
Option 2    </label> 
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Then use the following js code:

```
function toggleBackground(type) {
  if(type) {
    document.getElementById('wc-option-pay-deposit').style.background = 'color-1';
    document.getElementById('wc-option-pay-full').style.background = 'color-2';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('wc-option-pay-deposit').style.background = 'color-2';
    document.getElementById('wc-option-pay-full').style.background = 'color-1';
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to do without editing the original html as this is produced by a core file that I don't really want to edit?

Comment: Yes, you can add the onclick elements via js using selector.onclick = ....  I haven't dealt with this a lot and I don't think so, but it is possible that it may force you to create two separate functions.  It's also not the most efficient way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Add `:checked` for radio in css and `background-color: #ff0000;`

[Test](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/9gauts2c/2/)

```css
.wc-deposits-wrapper .wc-deposits-option li {
    padding: .5em 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 49%;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
.wc-deposits-wrapper .wc-deposits-option {
    list-style: none outside;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 2em;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  font-style: normal;
} 

input[type=radio] + label {
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="wc-deposits-wrapper wc-deposits-optional">
  <ul class="wc-deposits-option">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="wc_deposit_option" value="yes" id="wc-option-pay-deposit">
        <label for="wc-option-pay-deposit">
Option 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="wc_deposit_option" value="no" id="wc-option-pay-full" checked="checked">
        <label for="wc-option-pay-full">
Option 2</label> 
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nisarg. Thanks for your reply. This seem to change the label background instead of the li background.

Comment: While this is a better way then mine, the only problem is that there are not parent selectors in css, so it is impossible to get the li using solely css

Answer (score 0):

```
Please review solution link below. I used javascript to fixed this problem.

I hope this answer will be helpful for you
```

https://codepen.io/dev_aman/pen/YOxjpR

Comment: It is generally advised to include the code/snippet in the body of the answer; off-site resources may be subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JavaScript :

```js
function toggleItem ( input )
{
  input.closest( 'li' ).classList.toggle( 'wc-deposits-option-checked' );
}

function toggleOptions ()
{
  let 
    list = document.querySelector( '.wc-deposits-option' ),
    checked = list.querySelector( 'input:checked' );
    
  toggleItem( checked );
  
  list.addEventListener( 'input', () => {
  
    let target = event.target;
    
    toggleItem( target );
    toggleItem( checked );
    
    checked = target;
  
  });
}

toggleOptions();
```

```css
.wc-deposits-wrapper .wc-deposits-option li {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.wc-deposits-wrapper .wc-deposits-option {
  list-style: none outside;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.wc-deposits-option-checked
{
  background-color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<div class="wc-deposits-wrapper wc-deposits-optional">
  <ul class="wc-deposits-option">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="wc_deposit_option" value="yes" id="wc- 
    option-pay-deposit">
      <label for="wc-option-pay-deposit">
    Option 1    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="wc_deposit_option" value="no" id="wc-option- 
    pay-full" checked="checked">
      <label for="wc-option-pay-full">
    Option 2    </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```